# Python “Walk” directory to deal with xml

Tags: python, xml

I'm a new comer about python, and I code this program to deal with xml in os.walk().
This program can print "channel code" from different xml files, and they all named "mmiap.xml".

It is the code:

```
#coding=utf-8
import os
import  xml.dom.minidom


path = "H:\\Dev\\CODE\\MMwithwalk\\"

for root, dirs,files in os.walk(path):

    dom = xml.dom.minidom.parse('mmiap.xml')

    root = dom.documentElement

    bb = root.getElementsByTagName('channel')   #Get channel code from mmiap.xml

    b= bb[0]

    print (b.firstChild.data)
```

After run this program, it shows "FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'mmiap.xml'"

What's wrong? It seems that traversal is not walk depth. But I can't find the problem.

PS: If I drag a mmiap.xml to root directory, channel code will be printed normally.

Comment: ...what? You aren't actually using the `root`, so how exactly is Python supposed to know where you want it to look?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do -

```
dom = xml.dom.minidom.parse('mmiap.xml')
```

This would always only check inside the current directory, in which the script is being run, not inside the directory into which `os.walk()` has *walked*/recursed into .

You should first check whether `mmiap.xml` is inside the `files` list , if so, you should then use [`os.path.join()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) to join the `root` and the `filename` to create the actual filepath that you want to parse. Example -

```
import os
import os.path
import  xml.dom.minidom

path = "H:\\Dev\\CODE\\MMwithwalk\\"

for root, dirs,files in os.walk(path):
    if 'mmiap.xml' in files:
        filePath = os.path.join(root,'mmiap.xml')
        dom = xml.dom.minidom.parse(filePath)
        root = dom.documentElement
        bb = root.getElementsByTagName('channel')   #Get channel code from mmiap.xml
        b= bb[0]
        print (b.firstChild.data)
```

Comment: Thank you , and Glad I could be helpful :)